# How do I create a random String by sampling from alphanumeric characters?

Tags: random, rust, alphanumeric

I tried to compile the following code:

```
extern crate rand; // 0.6
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    rand::thread_rng()
        .gen_ascii_chars()
        .take(10)
        .collect::<String>();
}
```

but `cargo build` says:

```
warning: unused import: `rand::Rng`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use rand::Rng;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

error[E0599]: no method named `gen_ascii_chars` found for type `rand::prelude::ThreadRng` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
6 |         .gen_ascii_chars()
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The Rust compiler asks me to remove the `use rand::Rng;` clause, at the same time complaining that there is no `gen_ascii_chars` method. 
I would expect Rust to just use `rand::Rng` trait, and to not provide such a contradictory error messages. How can I go further from here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As explained in the [rand 0.5.0 docs](https://docs.rs/rand/0.5.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_ascii_chars), `gen_ascii_chars` is deprecated and you should use `sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)` instead.

```rust
use rand::{distributions::Alphanumeric, Rng}; // 0.8

fn main() {
    let s: String = rand::thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
        .take(7)
        .map(char::from)
        .collect();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: ```Alphanumeric``` isn't equals ```ascii```. ```ascii``` includes ```!@#$%^&*(){}[]:;"'<>?,./|\-_+=```, etc.

Comment: Docs page for `Alphanumeric` https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/distributions/struct.Alphanumeric.html

Comment: If you want ASCII, you can do `.sample_iter(Uniform::new(char::from(32), char::from(126))`

Answer (score 31):

With the introduction of [rand 0.8.4](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/0.8.4/CHANGELOG.md#084---2021-06-15), `rand` now contains `DistString` which contains a [more efficient](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/pull/1133) method of sampling a random alphanumeric string. Example from the rand docs:

```rust
use rand::distributions::{Alphanumeric, DistString};

let string = Alphanumeric.sample_string(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 16);
println!("{}", string);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b49c143c033c38cdf7575f7a0c609204

Comment: It's the recommanded way : The DistString trait provides an easier method of generating a random String, and offers more efficient allocation:

Answer (score 6):

An example with a **custom charset** and `rand` crate:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::iter;

fn generate(len: usize) -> String {
    const CHARSET: &[u8] = b"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let one_char = || CHARSET[rng.gen_range(0..CHARSET.len())] as char;
    iter::repeat_with(one_char).take(len).collect()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [random-string](https://docs.rs/random-string/latest/random_string/fn.generate.html) crate with your charset. You can install it by including `random-string` library in your `Cargo.toml`.

Take a look at the **example:**

```rust
// Import generate function
use random_string::generate;

// Your custom charset
let charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// Syntax:
// random_string::generate(length, your_charset);

// Usage:
println!("{}", generate(6, charset));
```

Answer (score -1):

Alphanumeric:

```
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let value: String = (0..100).map(|_| char::from(
        match rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..3) {
            1 => rand::thread_rng().gen_range(48..58),
            2 => rand::thread_rng().gen_range(65..91),
            _ => rand::thread_rng().gen_range(97..123)
        }
    )).collect();
    
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

**auR17xKQ8q7cjgUiMGzga8JzTRdYFAUZ7K7FtlGPJyNSRHXimO1g22F7Rf8cdTlhX1fcPfcvRH15v6U975pF7nDU6h0CDSvhI31O**

Full range of ascii:

```
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let value: String = (0..100).map(|_| char::from(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(32..127))).collect();
    
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

Example output:

**n/5;X D0}xbc8sEGY^cHSW3BiV-Ws "pojGKo93pbu0iZ#iT^f(L?S8j{-e^tbz^htQ"?{C'I+}ny|/[Qy.(>wGFzC%W,9*9j%Y_**

Comment: The question specifically asks for alphanumeric characters, so this is off-topic here.

Comment: Why this convoluted way when there is much better way, already explained in other answers?

Comment: @Chayim Friedman, because google for rust string generation leads here.

Comment: This is not a reason to give bad answers. In fact, this is a reason why not.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman, thank you for your concerns.