# How to generate random unicode strings in rust?

Tags: random, unicode, rust

I'm implementing a fuzzer and I'd like to generate random unicode strings. I came up with this solution, however, it's very inefficient and seldomly produces some string. Is there a better way to generate unicode strings?

Thank you.

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Error, Rng};
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut arr: Vec<u32> = vec![0; 1024];
    rng.try_fill(&mut arr[..])?;

    println!(
        "{:?}",
        arr.iter()
            .map(|u| char::try_from(*u))
            .flatten()
            .collect::<String>()
    );

    Ok(())
}
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ce2a612e79ee32c1390a2f53043a329)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a random String by sampling from alphanumeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275459/how-do-i-create-a-random-string-by-sampling-from-alphanumeric-characters)

Comment: No since, it creates just strings from alphanumeric characters. I'd like to generate string containing any unicode character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this:

```rust
fn get_random_string(len: usize) -> String {
    rand::thread_rng()
        .sample_iter::<char, _>(rand::distributions::Standard)
        .take(len)
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7ac7154e1f77d31ced9e3fb8d600e17)

You might want to filter control characters, if you want to print it. Also the character distribution is very unlike any UTF-8 strings you might encounter in the wild.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the secret sauce behind `sample_iter<char, Standard>` is the [implementation of the `Distribution<Char>` trait](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/9555338a270f408913068940f768a312561491f2/src/distributions/other.rs#L67)  for the `Standard` distribution type.